# Django REST Framework (AttributeError : Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field " " on serializer " ")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

`Got AttributeError` when attempting to get a value for field `Firstname`  in serializer `NameSerializer`.

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match
any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.

The original exception text was:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute Firstname.
```

**Error:**
[image: Error]

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Name, ForeName

class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = '__all__'

class ForeNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    forenames = NameSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ForeName
        fields= '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
import uuid

# create your models here
class ForeName(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Forename = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Forename

class Name(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Firstname = models.ForeignKey(ForeName, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                    related_name="forenames")
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import NameSerializer
from .models import Name

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def names_list(request):
    names = Name.objects.all()
    myname = NameSerializer(names)
    return Response({"restult": { 
        "Forename" : myname.data,
        }
```

Comment: Add full error traceback.

Comment: Error Traceback is added in top of serializers.py

Comment: This is not full traceback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `many=True` in your serializer when initializing with multiple instances.

`myname = NameSerializer(names,many=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, field names should be all lowercase, using underscores instead of camelCase, according to the official document. It's a convention that we all should follow. ex - first_name and fore_name

And as per your question, you should write
`myname = NameSerializer(names, many=True)`
in views.py, because you're trying to serialize multiple objects.